# InstallShield LE for Visual Studio 2013 - Installation Error ##IDS_ERROR_7## - ##IDS_ERROR_1####IDS_ERROR_2803##

Tags: visual-studio-2013, runtime-error, setup-project, installshield-le

This is the first time I've tried to use Install Shield LE in Visual Studio.

I went through the Project Assistant and basically just turned off almost all of the bells and whistles. No Installation Requirements, no Application Registry entries, and no to everything on the Installation Interview page. I did add a few additional files besides my Primary Output on the Application Files page, as well as desktop and start menu shortcuts on the Application Shortcuts page. All of that worked just fine.

Then I built the setup project and tried to install it.

Here is the error message I received: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDph3.png

The title of the message box says: `##IDS_ERROR_7##`

The body of the error box says: `##IDS_ERROR_1####IDS_ERROR_2803##`

I've not been able to find any useful information about this error message online.

I thought I was keeping this simple, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't made any manual changes to your dialogs:

Just right click on the install project in *Solution Explorer -> Clean*

Then rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ever encounters my original problem, I did finally figure out how to fix it. I scrapped the entire setup project first and added a new one from scratch, but that might not have been necessary.

Turns out what I really needed to do was compile the setup project just once with the default options selected on the Installation Interview section of the Project Assistant. After that, I noticed that the finished setup file was an exe now, instead of an msi file. I didn't mention that before because I didn't realize it was unusual, since I've never used install shield before.

Then I changed all the options on the Installation Interview page back off again and recompiled successfully with the settings I actually wanted. Still don't know why it doesn't work the first time, but that's how to fix this.

Comment: This didn't fix my issue but I'm definitely having the same issue as this and your answer was most helpful.  Right down the the setup.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the error is Windows Installer error 2803, it's:

Dialog View did not find a record for the dialog [2].

So it looks like your dialog sequence is broken, in the start or in the linking in the forwards and backwards directions.

You could install your MSI with an msiexec command that includes /l*v  and see exactly what's failing.

Comment: I never modified the dialog sequence at all, so I'm not sure how the default sequence could have become broken? Do you know how I can fix this? The msiexec log file you told me about is just loaded with IDS errors, mostly just repeating numbers 6, 12, & 13.